# How to throw exception when comparing with None on Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7:

Expression 1 (fine):

```
>>> 2 * None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Expression 2 (fine):

```
>>> None is None
True
```

Expression 3 (**bad**):

```
>>> 2 < None
False
```

Expression 4 (**bad**):

```
>>> None<None
False
```

Expression 5 (**bad**):

```
>>> None==None
True
```

I want to somehow force expressions 3, 4 and 5 to throw TypeError (same as in expression 1).

Python 3.4 is nearly there - only expression 5 returns True.

I need it in 2.7.

---

*My use case (if someone interested):*

*I'v made application that evaluates some expressions (example):*

```
d = a+b
e = int(a>b)
f = a if a<b else b if b<c else c
```

*Expressions are based on values (a, b and c) which comes from deserialized json.*
*Most of the time values (a, b and c) are integers, but sometimes (when value is missing) it is None. When value is missing and is used in some expressions then expression should return None (I was thinking about catching TypeError exception).*

*In case when a=None, b=1, c=2, exptected result is: d=None, e=None, f=None.*

*In case when a=1, b=2, c=None, expected result is: d=3, e=0, f=1*

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You can't change the magic methods of the standard classes, so unless you're open to different syntax (e.g. `compare(thing1, thing2)`), implementing your own classes to use (as http://stackoverflow.com/a/35165435/3001761 suggests) or actually patching Python itself, you're out of luck.

Comment: Well done for stating your use case in the question! A neat avoidance of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Why not use a simple try/except?

Comment: Padaric Cunningham: the problem is that: (2 < None) is not throwing an exception....

Comment: Yes but 2 + None will, you could force an error, an isinstance check would also work

Comment: Padaric Cunningham: (simple) expression: "f = a if a<b else b if b<c else c" with extra isinstance checking for None would be much more complicated.

Comment: @vac, it is four lines

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: with more values it would be more complicated. For me, It would be the best to have same equation in one line, and it would be nice to keep it readable (by end user).

Comment: @vac, how even if you managed to raise an error would you be able to fit the logic into a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the behavior of `None`. However, you can implement your own type which has the behavior you want. As a starting point:

```
class CalcNum(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, o):
        return CalcNum(self.value + o.value)

    def __lt__(self, o):
        if self.value is None or o.value is None:
            # Pick one:
            # return CalcNum(None)
            raise TypeError("Can't compare Nones")

        return CalcNum(self.value < o.value)
```

Comment: It can be best answer but I'm wondering if there is no other way (for example override operator?). With your answer, in my use case, I would have to replace all values which comes from json deserializer with CalcNum instances. This would be problematic: especially in case of some equation as g=math.sin(a)+math.cos(b). I would have to use g=math.sin(a.value)+math.cos(b.value). It doesn't look nice.

Comment: @vac: Unfortunately you can't just override the addition operator in general. `a + b` is equivalent to `a.__add__(b)` - each class (including `int`) implements addition itself. You would indeed have to replace all the instances with CalcNum. You can make `math.sin(CalcNum(a))` work by implementing `def __float__(self): return float(self.value)`, but probably the best option is to implement your own expression parser (or use [`compiler.parse()`](http://tinyurl.com/pycomp), and evaluate them yourself, deciding what to do for each one, instead of riding on Python's `eval`.

Comment: implementing `__float__` in `CalcNum` could be a nice idea. `compiler.parse` also sounds promising. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use issinstance:

```
from numbers import Number


def pre(a, b, c):
    if not isinstance(a, Number) or not isinstance(b, Number):
        return None, None, None
    if not isinstance(c, Number):
        return a + b, a > b, a if a < b else b
    return a + b, a > b,  a if a < b else b if b < c else c
```

If any number in a calculation is None you return all Nones, if c is None you return your calculations excluding the if b < c else c and if they are all numbers then return all the expressions:

```
In [53]: pre(None,1,2)
Out[53]: (None, None, None)

In [54]: pre(1,2,None)
Out[54]: (3, False, 1)

In [55]: pre(None,None,None)
Out[55]: (None, None, None)

In [56]: pre(3,4,5)
Out[56]: (7, False, 3)
```